# IPTables disrupts WebServer Connections on Startup

Tags: linux, configuration, centos, webserver, iptables

Alright, this has not happened before in my past experience in coding and using Linux but right now, when I start up IPTables, I cannot access my website in every way possible. SSH still works.

My operating system: 
`CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)`

And the things inside my IPTables:

```
# sample configuration for iptables service
# you can edit this manually or use system-config-firewall
# please do not ask us to add additional ports/services to this default configuration
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

If anyone could help me fix this problem, it'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iptables -I INPUT 3 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```

If you could read the manual of iptables, it also would be great.

Comment: IPTables gave me a message saying:
`iptables: Index of insertion too big.`

Any other methods to resolving this?

Comment: It can't be too big, you have 5 lines in INPUT chain already.

Comment: I think I will try editing it manually in the rules file. I'll update you if it works or not.

Comment: That worked out well! Thank you! ^_^

Comment: Also save the rules if you are adding it through cli for persistence.